# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI Spring MVC 4

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a problem.
I'm new on Spring MVC. I follow an example of Spring MVC 4+Hibernate CRUD.

But I couldn't run mapping on spring mvc.

I use intellij idea and tomcat server.

I'll share my code. I miss something or I do something wrong but I can't see.

Here is my AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "java.*")
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(){
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
}
```

Here is my AppInitializer.java :

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/");
}
}
```

Here is my EmployeeController.java :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;

@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;


@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/list"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listEmployees(Model model){
    List<Employee> employees = employeeService.findAllEmployees();
    model.addAttribute("allEmployees",employees);
    return "allemployees";
}
}
```

Additionally this class I have allemployees.jsp views page under the WEB-INF/views and Employee model,service and dao class and hibernate configuration class.

All this things looks well. When I run project on ide and entry this url http:/localhost:8080/ouremployee I see index.jsp "Hello World" page. After that I entry http:/localhost:8080/ouremployee/list I should see allemployees.jsp but I got this error :

```
WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ouremployee/list] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Where am I wrong? Could you help me please?

Comment: Can you try to change `@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/list"},method = RequestMethod.GET)` in `@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/list","/allemployees"},method = RequestMethod.GET)` ?

Comment: Oh sorry I wrote wrong.I already tried to my request as http:/localhost:8080/ouremployee/list. I'll fix on entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. Firstly I want to thank you for your interests to my issue.

My project structure like this on Intellij IDEA

-src
  -main
    -java
        -com
            -sample
              .
              .
  -resources
       .
       .
  -webapp
       .

and I marked as source root directory to src. After that I try to entry parameter to @ComponentScan "java.com.sample" Intellij doesn't accept that and I entried as java.* and my mapping doesn't work.

I tried to marked as a source directory to java and I entry to @ComponentScan as "com.sample" Intellij accept that. After to finished this I run my project and spring mapping run as well.

I want to say; my problem cause is spring mvc couldn't find scan packages because of my wrong prokect structure definition. I fixed this and mapping works correctly.

Thank you for whole of you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using DispatcherConfig for the class name? Let me know if it's working / not working.

Comment: Ok I'll try and I'll brief about result. But according to my researchs It doesn't matter Spring MVC config class name but I'm not sure I'll try maybe it works.

Comment: I think you can't use your ComponentScan configuration with the value "java.*", instead use packages name that closely represent your controller classes package. And don't use * on it.

Comment: I solved 30 minutes ago. I'll explain as an answer. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 'ouremployee' in the url?
Is that your app base name in run configuration?

I would try http:/localhost:8080/  or  http:/localhost:8080/list  urls to see if that would give me any different results.

Comment: Yes it's base name in run/debug configuration.Does it matter? If It'll work as localhost:8080/list Will it work as localhost:8080/ouremployee/list?Ok I'll try and I'll brief you about result.